# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in ..\wp-content\plugins\revslider\admin\revslider-admin.class.php on line 519

Tags: php, wordpress, revolution-slider

When I am trying to use `revslider - wordpress plugin` with `TGM-Plugin-Activation-develop` for wordpress, I am having php warning below, while I change to my template from any other template in wordpress admin panel => appearance => themes:

`Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in ..\wp-content\plugins\revslider\admin\revslider-admin.class.php on line 519`

How to remove this warning from my wordpress admin panel?

Comment: Readibility extensions

Answer (score -1):

This function is comparing two arrays. The second parameter of this function is waiting for array, and you give it null value.

One possibility is repair your code, second possibility is hide the warning. If you want only hide the warning, you can put this lines into begin of index.php file.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_NONE);
```

...after it all errors and warnings will be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for reply..   And I will go with hiding it. but this is not working for me, Can you please tell me the exact place in index.php ?  right now i have putting it before  `get_header();` method in `index.php`, but issue remains same.

Comment: Put it to the baseFolder/wp-admin/index.php to the line 8 If not help, I need to see the source code revslider-admin.class.php